# Why does stall warning system require 4 minutes of AC power on the 737NG?

Tags: boeing-737, avionics, stall

Is it related to the Stall Management Yaw Damper (SMYD) computers starting? But the number 1 stall test is working with no need for waiting.

Please provide sources, if available.